# Firebase In-App-Messaging wont show in campaign, but also work in test device

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-analytics, firebase-in-app-messaging

I am using firebase in-ap-messaging with analytics, and my campaign wont show if i publish, but also work in test device with test campaign.
in build.gradle;

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.0.1')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
```

with that analytics event fragment OnCreate() Method

```
Firebase.analytics.logEvent("HomePage",null)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shown couple of hours later after publish campaign.